# Conditionally created array not seen after creation

Tags: ruby, shell, tac

Suppose I am writing a type of `tac` in Ruby that will reverse the lines of a file or stream given to it.

So `Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n` [Ruby script] => `Line 3\nLine 2\nLine1\n`

Here are some test files:

```
printf "f1, Line %s\n" $(seq 3) >f1
printf "f2, Line %s\n" $(seq 5) >f2
printf "f3, Line %s\n" $(seq 7) >f3
```

A straightforward way to write that is:

```
ruby -e ' # read each ARGF and reverse it
$<.each_line{|line| 
    lines=Array.new if $<.file.lineno==1 
    lines.unshift(line)
    p lines if $<.eof?
}'
```

However, with that version, I get the error:

```
-e:4:in `block in <main>': undefined method `unshift' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    lines.unshift(line)
         ^^^^^^^^
    from -e:2:in `each_line'
    from -e:2:in `each_line'
    from -e:2:in `<main>'
```

I can fix that by changing the script to:

```
ruby -e 'BEGIN{lines=[]}
$<.each_line{|line| 
    lines=Array.new if $<.file.lineno==1 
    lines.unshift(line)
    p lines if $<.eof?
}'
```

But why is the `BEGIN` block necessary? Isn't the `lines` array created with the first go through? It seems like a throw-away definition of the array...

---

The final version there does work:

```
cat f1 | ruby -e 'BEGIN{lines=[]}
$<.each_line{|line| 
    lines=Array.new if $<.file.lineno==1 
    lines.unshift(line)
    p lines if $<.eof?
}' - f2 f3
["f1, Line 3\n", "f1, Line 2\n", "f1, Line 1\n"]
["f2, Line 5\n", "f2, Line 4\n", "f2, Line 3\n", "f2, Line 2\n", "f2, Line 1\n"]
["f3, Line 7\n", "f3, Line 6\n", "f3, Line 5\n", "f3, Line 4\n", "f3, Line 3\n", "f3, Line 2\n", "f3, Line 1\n"]
```

But why do I have to define `lines` in the BEGIN block only to define it again in the loop? It does not matter what `lines` is defined as in the `BEGIN` block; it can be numerical, boolean, hash, whatever -- but the name has to exist.

Ideas?

```
% ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin23]
```

---

Thanks for the comments and answers. Please see this Python as I think why my *muscle memory* may have gotten confused:

```
def f():
    # local li is created first iteration and used on subsequent... 
    # Similar to Ruby, li is local to this scope of f()
    for x in [1,2,3,4]:
        if x==1: li=[] 
        li.append(x)

    return li
```

Comment: I can even have `BEGIN{lines=0}` so it is in not a type issue -- it is a name issue.

Comment: The block created a variable scope and therefore, `lines` will be `nil` on the 2nd iteration. You have to define `lines` outside the block.

Comment: @Stefan: Does the part before `... if $<.file.lineno==1` constitute a block that is separate from the `each_line` block? I guess that would explain it...

Comment: No it doesn't. But the block is executed multiple times and each invocation "resets" the variables. You could try `for line in $<`

Comment: @Stefan: `for line in $< do [same inner part] end` does indeed work without predefining `lines`. What is the difference?

Comment: It's the scope actually, from the [`for` Loop](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop) docs: _"The `for` loop is similar to using each, but does not create a new variable scope."_

Comment: You have a typo. You named your variable inside the block by  `|line|`, but refer to it as `lines`.

Comment: @user1934428: Not a typo. `line` is a string read from `ARGF` and `lines` is an array of those strings...

Comment: @dawg : Ah, you are right, obviously! But it is a local variable, and defined only on the first line. In the subsequent iterations, it is undefined. If the OP would have written `$lines`, it would make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it has nothing to do with Unix pipes or input / output. You get the same error in a Ruby-only variant, e.g.

```rb
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  ary = [] if i == 1 
  ary.unshift(i)
end
# undefined method `unshift' for nil:NilClass
```

The exception is raised because `ary` is defined on the 1st iteration but not on the subsequent iterations – here, `ary` will be `nil`. In Ruby, a block creates a new [local variable scope](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variable+Scope) and

> [...] any local variables created inside it do not leak to the surrounding scope.

This also applies to calling the same block multiple times:

```rb
def foo
  yield
  yield
end

foo do
  p before: defined? a
  a = 1
  p after: defined? a
end
```

Output:

```rb
{:before=>nil}
{:after=>"local-variable"}
{:before=>nil}
{:after=>"local-variable"}
```

As you can see, the variable scope is not retained between block invocations. The same applies to `each` which also calls the block multiple times.

To get the desired behavior, you can simply create the variable *outside* the block, e.g.:

```rb
ary = []
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  ary.unshift(i)
end
ary #=> [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I do understand (I thought!!) the local variable from Python. (See edit to question) What is a *surprise* is that the local creation isn't continuous. In Python, if you create a local scope variable it remains valid until the entire block goes out of scope. It tricks MY brain anyway to view `[1, 2, 3].each do |i| ...j` as not having CONTINUOUS scope for `j` rather than a NEW local scope on each iteration.

Comment: Also: If variable scope is not retained inbetween invocations, why is setting `BEGIN{lines=[object not a list]}` but then `lines` becomes a list first time though the block with `lines=Array.new if $<.file.lineno==1 ` *and then the character of the object being a list* is continued in subsequent iterations. THAT is suspicious...

Comment: @dawg from the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variable+Scope): _"Variables defined in an outer scope appear inner scope"_. `lines` is defined in the outer scope. On the first iteration you assign an array to it but that assignment isn't limited to the inner scope because the variable was defined outside. There's no outer `lines` and inner `lines`, it's only one variable (the outer one). If you assign something to it, it remains.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is right in your title [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> ***Conditionally created*** array not seen after creation

You only create the array *conditionally*. Which means, there are conditions where the array *isn't* created. To be precise, the array is only created if `$<.file.lineno` equals `1`. In every other case, the array is not created.

You have to make sure the array is created *in any case*.

The simplest way to do that is to move the assignment out of the block:

```ruby
lines = []

$<.each_line { |line| 
  lines.unshift(line)
  p lines if $<.eof?
}
```

You can do the same thing with the printing as well:

```ruby
lines = []

$<.each_line { |line| 
  lines.unshift(line)
}

p lines
```

This now allows you to rewrite the loop in point-free style:

```ruby
lines = []

$<.each_line(&lines.method(:unshift)

p lines
```

However, I don't see the point in lazily iterating over the input if you are going to end up building the whole array in memory anyway. Why not just do something like this instead:

```ruby
p $<.readlines.reverse
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! *Why not just do something like this instead:* `p $<.readlines.reverse` Like `tac` I wanted to go though multiple files and potentially STDIN. If you do `$<.readlines.reverse` it will read ALL the input available on ARGF in one go, not each input in turn...